# Can you get the style of the first child div and append it to the parent then remove all the divs

Tags: jquery

The program I'm working in I can wrap images with a div 
and I can name it's ID so it's like this:

```
<div id="caro" style=" position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:602px; height:0px;  z-index:2;">

          <div id="SGROBJ7DCC09717112EB0" style=" position:absolute; top:68px; left:148px; width:602px; height:200px;  z-index:3;">
            <img src="Untitled_1/goim003.jpg" width=602 height=200 border=0 alt="">
          </div>

          <div id="SGROBJ7DCC09717112FF0" style=" position:absolute; top:68px; left:148px; width:602px; height:200px;  z-index:4;">
            <img src="Untitled_1/goim004.jpg" width=602 height=200 border=0 alt="">
          </div>

          <div id="SGROBJ7DCC09717113140" style=" position:absolute; top:68px; left:148px; width:600px; height:200px;  z-index:5;">
            <img src="Untitled_1/goim005.jpg" width=600 height=200 border=0 alt="">
          </div>
 </div>
```

I want to get that style from the first child and append it to the parent #caro div
Then remove all the div's around the images. (Those SGROBJ... ID's change)
That I can then use these for a carousel 
**So I want to end up with:**

```
<div id="caro" style=" position:absolute; top:68px; left:148px; width:602px; height:200px;  z-index:3;">
            <img src="Untitled_1/goim003.jpg" width=602 height=200 border=0 alt="">
            <img src="Untitled_1/goim004.jpg" width=602 height=200 border=0 alt="">
            <img src="Untitled_1/goim004.jpg" width=602 height=200 border=0 alt="">
            <img src="Untitled_1/goim005.jpg" width=600 height=200 border=0 alt="">
 </div>
```

Comment: Then don't wrap it in a div and don't assign them an ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply the style from the first child:

```
$('#caro').attr('style', $('#caro > div:first').attr('style'));
```

To remove the DIVs leaving the images intact:

```
$('#caro > div > img').unwrap();
```

To it all in one statement:

```
$('#caro').attr('style', $('#caro > div:first').attr('style')).find('div > img').unwrap();
```

Answer (score 1):

do you mean something like:

```
var childStyle = $("div#caro > div:first").attr("style");
$("div#caro").attr("style", childStyle);
$("div#caro").find("img").each(function() {
    $(this).unwrap("div");
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sj6rq/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#caro').attr('style', $('#caro').children('div').first().attr('style'))
  .children('div').each(function(i,elem) {
      $(elem).replaceWith($('img', elem));
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/g6Qxh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function removeDiv(){
    var imgs = $('#caro').find('img').clone();
    console.log(imgs);
    $('#caro').empty();
    $('#caro').append(imgs);
}
```